# Debugging a function being called from notebook in jupyter-lab

Tags: debugging, jupyter-lab

I have a notebook in jupyter-lab, lets say it is as simple as this:

```
import importlib
import data_exploration as de
importlib.reload(de)
de.test(3,5)
```

In the data_exploration.py file I have the following function:

```
def test(a,b):
    c=a+b
    d=a-b
    return c,d
```

I am able to set a breakpoint in the .py file, but when I run the code from the notebook the execution doesn't stop at the breakpoint. How can I connect the debugger in the notebook and in the source file. Please also see the attached images:

[[image: The notebook][1]]

Comment: Were you able to figure this out? Can you add an answer if you have any workaround in these situations?